# Как сделать проверку на наличие уже зарегистрированного пользователя mysql, python?

Tags: python, mysql

Делал по своему старому коду, но почему-то не удаётся корректно обработать, вот код:

```
    try:
        enter = f'SELECT * FROM user_logs WHERE user_id = {user_id}'
        if enter == 0:
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO `user_logs` (`user_id`, `verification`, `balance`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(insert_query, (user_id, verification, balance))
            conn.commit()
            print('good!')
        else:
            print('Вы уже зарегистрированы!')
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)


try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

create_log('ttt', 't', 1011000)
```

В консоль выводит:

**Вы уже зарегистрированы!**

Кто знает решение проблемы, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: так как `enter = f'SELECT * FROM user_logs WHERE user_id = {user_id}'`, то условие `enter == 0` всегда ложно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В переменной **enter** у вас строка с SQL запросом. А не результат выполнения этого запроса. Да и сам запрос не очень корректный.

Т.е. должно быть что-то вроде

```
#считаем число записей у которых user_id содержит указанное значение
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_logs WHERE user_id = %s"
cur = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, (user_id))
#получаем число найденных записей
enter = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: Ну зачем заставлять сервер делать лишнюю никому не нужную работу? `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM user_logs WHERE user_id = %s)`. Тогда сервер гарантированно прервёт поиск, как только обнаружит первую же соответствующую условиям отбора запись. Причём это актуально даже при поиске по уникальному выражению, хотя профит в этом случае и малозаметен.

Comment: Автор текст SQL  запроса сравнивает с 0 Тут уж не до ракетных технологий.

Comment: Я не об ошибке автора, а о неоптимальности кода в ответе. А то автор научится не только хорошему, но и плохому...

Comment: Ну возможно вы и правы втыкая оптимизацию везде, где она даже не нужна. Но на мой взгляд для начала разработчик должен понять в чем разница между ``SELECT *`` и ``SELECT COUNT(*)``, а уже потом переходить к высоким материям. Которые вероятней всего ему и не понадобятся. Потому, что к примеру эта задача правильней и быстрей решается в один SQL запрос когда сразу проверили и добавили запись в случае необходимости.  А так можно  еще добавить лок на таблицу, чтобы гонок не возникло. И т.д. и т.п.

Comment: не могли вы написать подробно, а то я не понимаю максимально, буду благодарен!